# Long screen timeout on lock screen Oreo 8.0.0

Tags: lock-screens, screen, 8.0-oreo, mi-a1, screen-timeout

After the Oreo 8.0.0 update on MI A1, the screen timeout when the lock screen appears, takes the same value as the sleep timeout.

Usually when there was Nougat, the timeout on lock screen would be very short (5 seconds I guess).

Is this is a bug or intentional feature? Also is it only on Mi A1 or all phones running Oreo 8.0.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I couldn't find out the reason for long lock screen timeout, I made a quick solution to get it back working as it was earlier.

Here's the solution, implemented as a flow in the **[Automate for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate)** app.

Flow URL: [Short lock screen timeout[VM]](http://llamalab.com/automate/community/flows/21993)

[image]